# Using data from yaml to initialize app config variables in java classes & javascript

Tags: java, javascript, yaml

I need to store the configuration constants in java web app in a .yaml file. I am expecting that  these config constants's values may then be used to initialize their corresponding copies as `static final` constants defined in java classes!?

Or otherwise, do I need to read from the .yaml each time I need the value in java classes?

P.S.:  I also need to copy/use these constants within my JavaScript files.

Comment: You'll have to write some sort of code to read from the YAML files. What you do in that code is up to you. You could generate Java and/or JavaScript, or you could build a run-time data structure.